# angularjs - how to disable model binding when editing item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have such part of view:

```
<tbody>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate:reverse" data-id="{{user.Id}}" class="table-row">
    <td>
      <div class="contacts-cell">
        {{user.FirstName}}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="editContact(user)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-person"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and modal where i'm editing my data:

```
<div class="modal custom" id="new-person" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" modal-center data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">      
      <form class="form-horizontal first-modal" role="form" name="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="onCancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="column-left">            
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': submittedContact && contactForm.firstName.$invalid }">
              <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
              <span class="input-nonedit" data-ng-show="isShowWindow">{{person.FirstName}}</span>
              <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control on-input" data-ng-model="person.FirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter Name" data-ng-hide="isShowWindow" maxlength="100" required/>
            </div>
            </div>           
          </div>
          <div class="column-right">            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn-edit pull-right" data-ng-click="updateContact()" data-target="#new-person">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
$scope.editContact = function(userToCopy) {
        $scope.person = userToCopy;
        $scope.initialUser = angular.copy(userToCopy);
      };


$scope.updateContact = function() {
    if ($scope.contactForm.$valid) {
      $http.put(settings.apiBaseUri + '/myapp/contacts', $scope.person, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .success(function(response) {
        }).error(function(err, status) {

        });
    }
  };
```

i didn't understand: why in table when i edit in modal, as background i see that my table is changing? why, there is no binding (i think so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you run the editContact function you make the $scope.person point to the same object as userToCopy, which in this case is $scope.user, so when you change $scope.person the $scope.user is change too.

Use $scope.initialUser instead $scope.person, this way the $scope.initialUser is a copy of the original user and not the same pointer, so changes on this object **does not reflect on the other one.**

```
<span class="input-nonedit" data-ng-show="isShowWindow">{{initialUser.FirstName}}</span>

$scope.updateContact = function() {
    if ($scope.contactForm.$valid) {
      $http.put(settings.apiBaseUri + '/myapp/contacts', $scope.initialUser, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .success(function(response) {
        }).error(function(err, status) {

        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: please add code, i didn't understand for 100% what you mean and where to change

Comment: So after you close the modal you need to update the scope.user to the new data. This is how things are working.

Comment: "So after you close the modal you need to update the scope.user to the new data. This is how things are working"  -  which practice is best of doing that?

Comment: You can put on the close button modal function that will do $scope.user equal to $scope. initialUser or use events.

Comment: this i know)) just that seems that i need to iterate via table and find this item, becouse i didn't store scope.user

Comment: maybe there are any other solutions? something like directive etc? becouse so i need to change core logic...